# TinyMCE не работает если CSS подключен

Tags: tinymce

когда CSS не подключен кнопки поля tinyMCE работают, но когда они подключены, то toolbar не работает. Подскажите, в чём проблема?
HTML

```
<head>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
        <script>
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "#tinymce"
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <div class="news">

        <div class="news_main-news">
          <div class="header">
            <a id="title_btn" href="#"><h1 id="header_title">hot pepper</h1></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="left-news-column">

        <div class="left-news-column_conteiner">
            <div class="left-news-column__block">
                <h1>Last election</h1>
                    <p class="view"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="left-news-column__block">
                    <h1>The faster </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="left-news-column__block">
                    <h1>Main street</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea id="tinymce"></textarea>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body{
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://html5book.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/background54.png);
}

/*a{
  height: 20px;
}*/

.navbar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.navbar_link{
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 15px;
  color: black;

}

.navbar_link:before{
  content: " ";
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top:60px ;
  display:none;
}

.navbar_link:hover:before{
  display: inline;
}

#log:hover:before{
  display: none;
}

#log{
  position: relative;
  left: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.icon{
  height: 35px;
}

.news{
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.news_main-news{
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(wallpaper.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.left-news-column{
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 332;
}

.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  position: relative;
  top: 85%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: .5;
}

#header_title{
  font-size:auto;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 2343;
  opacity: 1;
}

.left-news-column__block{
  border: 1px #f2eaea solid;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 70px;
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```